# Proper way to initialize nested fields in Rails forms

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller

I'd like to understand what's the "proper" way to initialize the nested fields of a model.

Let's say you have some nested fields for a model:

```
class User

  has_one :address   
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :address
end
```

And you need to initialize those attributes (`address` in this case) to use them in a `fields_for` call.

So far I've thought of three ways to do this.

First, `after_initialize` hook on the model:

```
class User
  after_initialize :init_address

  protected
  def init_address
    address ||= build_address
end
```

Then we have initialization in the controller:

```
class UsersController
  def new    
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_address
  end
end
```

And finally, we can have a helper method to do it for us:

```
module FormHelpers
  def setup_user(user)
    user.address ||= user.build_address
    user
  end
end

# view

<%= form_for setup_user(@user)... %>
```

Is there anything resembling a standard or a "best practice" for this scenario? How do you do it and why?

Comment: In the lack of a better solution, I ended up writing a gem that takes care of this: https://github.com/febuiles/auto_build

Comment: Looks like an old post. Which version of Rails are you using?

Answer (score 2):

I think that if the nested attribute doesn't make sense at all without the parent model, building and initialization of these nested models should be the responsibility of the parent model.

I don't see why the `UsersController` should care about how the `@user.addresses` are built or initialized. For me, giving the controller this responsibility, would probably imply that on `create` he should be the one that parsed and built the nested attributes (which, happens in the model).

I would go for the first approach.

Comment: The first approach fails in case of nested forms. The nested object is reinitialized and the nested form may fail validations.

Answer (score 0):

i believe that build_address is already built in for rails after u declare a has_one association, so you don't need to write that bit urself. 
and if the form is called only from the new action, what u really need is only the controller bit, and nothing else

Comment: There was a typo in the code, instead of `build_address` the method should be called `init_address`. Hope it's clearer now.

Comment: I thought it was `@user.addresses.build`?

Comment: @macek: For one item (has_one relationship) you use build_field. For multiple items (has_many) you do use fields.build.

Comment: @FedericoBuiles thanks; I missed that it was a `has_one` relationship.